# Creating Floating Action Button (FAB) using Floaty in IOS

Tags: ios, swift

I have created a Floating action button like shown in image [https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKUdr.png] using floaty in swift. The point is I want to navigate to another view controller by clicking on Plus button. I can do it by following code but i want to know whether there is way to directly navigate to another view controller on clicking on plus button. Please support me if there is way to do it. Thankyou.

```
func loadFAB(){
  let image = UIImage(named: "add")
  let floaty = Floaty()
  
      floaty.buttonColor = color
      floaty.plusColor = UIColor.white
        
      floaty.addItem(icon: image, handler:{ item in
   
      //navigate to another page
      self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "idnewPageSegue", sender: self)})

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you may use like below

```
let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "nextView") as! NextViewController
self.present(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
floatyView.addItem(title: "Next"){ item in
       
let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
        let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NextViewController") as! NextViewController
        self.present(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
        
    }
    self.view.addSubview(floatyView)
```